# Encapsulating mappings in separate classes

Tags: c#, linq

I want to make LINQ projection on a query. For this I use the [LINQ Projector](http://linqprojector.codeplex.com/) library. The project is inspired by this [post](http://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/stop-using-automapper-in-your-data-access-code) by Paul Hiles.

This library allows you to make the following:

```
public class Blog
{
   public int Id {get;set;}
   public string Name {get;set;}
   public ICollection<Post> Posts {get;set;}
}

public class BlogView
{
   public int Id {get;set;}
   public string BlogName {get;set;}
   public int NumberOfPosts {get;set;}
}

var person = new DataContext().Blog.Project().To<BlogView>(
   //custom mappings
    m=>m
   .Map(t=>t.BlogName, s=>s.Name)
   .Map(t=>t.NumberOfPosts, s=>s.Posts.Count());       
).First();
```

I like it, but  I want to encapsulate custom mapping in classes. The method `To`  can accept `Action<Mapper<Person, PersonView>>` for this example.

What is best and flexible way to do it? (base class for all mapping classes, generics)